# Comparing Object (facts) in working memory in drools

Tags: java, drools, rules, drools-flow

I am reading an excel sheet through DRT (rule template) and then converting it in to Object of a class through a static method in Java class. and also inserting it in to working memroty. In this way, working memory is filled up with all the facts from Excel sheet.

Now, I am sending facts through Java class in INSERT() through session. 
I need to match two similar object and return the matched objects from working memory.
As for Example:

Read from Excel and inserted in to the Working memory.

```
Person(name == "Kumar", Age == 60, status == true);
```

Now in Java class, through session I am inserting the following object:

```
Person(name == "Kumar", Age == 60 );
```

and then I need to set `Status = true` by comparing the two Objects.

I need to write the rule that will compare both objects.

Please suggest some way.

Thanks
Shorav

Comment: What would be a "similar" object? One that has the same name and age? Should status be set to true in both facts? Also, if there is a third, fourth, fifth,... "similar" fact with same name and age, should they all be set to true?

Comment: Yes, if all the passing facts i.e. Age and Name is matching, I need to set that object status to true. ad return it in to java classes.

Comment: if more than one facts would be passed; all should set to be true/false.

Comment: instead of generating rules from Excel sheet through DRT; I am writing rules for comparing the objects and finding appropriate Object from Working memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have to assume that it is possible that there are three or more "similar" facts it's best to do it like this:

```
rule "find same name and age"
when
    $p1: Person( $name: name, $age: age, status == false )
    $p2: Person( name == name, age == $age, status == false, this != $p1 )
    accumulate( $p: Person( name == name, age == $age, status == false );
                $list: collectList( $p ) )
then
    for( int i = 0; i < $list.size(); i++ ){
        Person p = (Person)$list.get(i);
        update( p ){ setStatus( true ) }
    }
end
```

Comment: I will be implementing it. BTW, How can I read excel and then insert the data as a fact. Thanks for your time.

Comment: IF you dig into the Drools source, you should find code for reading an Excel file: org/drools/decisiontable/parser/xls/ExcelParser.java, org/drools/decisiontable/SpreadsheetCompiler.java etc. - It's based on Listeners, which may not be the straightforward approach you might have in mind, but it should contain references to some useful classes.